# Can I hide a specific Google Now place card?

Tags: google-now

Google Now is very cool, and I like how it shows places you may be interested in nearby.

I'm wondering though, is there any way to tell it "No, I'm ***not*** interested in that place, please don't show it to me again"?

Note that I don't want to turn off the nearby places cards entirely, I want to see those, I just want to dismiss **specific** places and not see cards for them again.

Can I do this?

Note also, if there is a way, it doesn't necessarily need to be in Google Now, ... if there's even a way to go on the web and add the place to an ignore list or something or anything.

Comment: You can swipe them away, but I don't think that prevents them from coming back.

Comment: No, it definitely does not. I keep swiping it away, and it keeps coming back.

Answer (score 2):

An individual place can be swiped away, but there is no way to tell Google Now to never show you a specific place again.